# Auto-adjust font-size in defined DIV with changing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to auto-translate a text on my website by exchanging it with the same sentence in another language every few seconds, but this is not where my problem lies.

I already got the JS for this set-up, it looks like this:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var languages = ["¡Hola, me llamo X! Bienvenido a mi página web.", "Hallo, ich heiße X. Willkommen auf meiner Webseite.", "你好, 我叫 X。欢迎来到我的网站。"];
    var counter = 0;
    var $exc = $('#translate')
    setInterval(function () {
        $exc.text(languages[counter++]);
        if (counter >= languages.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 1600)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="translate">你好, 我叫 Jan。欢迎来到我的网站。</h2>
```

Now I want to adjust the `font-size` of my `h2` to always fit 1 line to prevent shifting the following text further up and down, when the text-length changes.
Looks especially bad on mobile.

I tried using the open-source JS "jtextfill", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of changing `font-size` of text is not hard here.

1. Save default (current) `font-size` of text to some variable.
2. After applying translation apply default `font-size`
3. Compare width of container (in our case it will be `body`, but you can change it) and width of text element (`#translate` in current case).
4. If width of text element is bigger than width of container decrease `font-size` by some value (for example by `0.1px`) and go to step 3. If no then that's all.

Don't forget to make you `h2` inline block to make it width defined by content and add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent text moving to next line and allow our calculations.

Demo:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var languages = ["¡Hola, me llamo Jan! Bienvenido a mi página web.", "Hallo, ich heiße Jan. Willkommen auf meiner Webseite.", "你好, 我叫 Jan。欢迎来到我的网站。"];

    var counter = 0;
    var $exc = $('#translate');
        
    var defaultFontSize = parseFloat($exc.css("font-size"));
    
    function adjustFontSize() {
        var fontSize = defaultFontSize;
        $exc.css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
 
        while ($("body").width() < $exc.width()) {
          fontSize -= 0.1;
          $exc.css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
        }
    };
    
    adjustFontSize();
    
    setInterval(function () {
        $exc.text(languages[counter++]);
        
        adjustFontSize();
        
        if (counter >= languages.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 1600)
})
```

```css
body {
  /* just 300px width for demo */
  width: 300px;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  border-right: 1px dotted gray;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#translate {
  /* take width and disable line wrapping */
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="translate">你好, 我叫 Jan。欢迎来到我的网站。</h2>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Indeed a pretty simple, yet efficient solution. Didn't think of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

using it looks like this:

```css
p {
    font-size: 4vw;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work due to varying text-length. Thanks for the suggestion, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work:

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

```
$('h2').flowtype({
 minFont : 10,
 maxFont : 40,
 minimum : 500,
 maximum : 1200,
 fontRatio : 70
});
```

Comment: Didn't quite work, sadly. Thank you for your suggestion, though. :)